# How to see stdout when debugging unit tests?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, stdout

I'm debugging unit tests in Android Studio. The tests were written by someone else and are full of calls to `System.out.println()`. When I run the unit tests, that output is visible in the **Run** tab. When I *debug* the unit tests, the output is nowhere to be seen.

Is there a way to see stdout when debugging a unit test in Android Studio?

I don't want to change the `println()` calls, but even if I did, logcat doesn't work either because these are unit tests running within Android Studio, not on a device.

Comment: Why not just print to a file and read from that?

Comment: I'm debugging someone else's code and don't want to re-write hundreds of log messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Edit Configurations to "Show console when message is printed out"
[image: Edit Configuration]

The unit test code is as follows:
[image: Unit test stdout code]

The logs can be seen in the debug -> console

[image: debug value]

If break point is set and stepped through you can view in the same section

[image]

Comment: Actually, I think the answer was simply "look in debug > console", and editing the run configuration isn't actually needed, but at any rate my problem is solved, so thank you.